# How to update a column to 2 decimals

Tags: sql

I have a column `PRICESTABLE.PRICE` with values like the following

```
12.356898
13.587988
```

I need to make an update to `PRICETABLE` to update the prices like these:

```
12.350000
13.580000
```

Notice I don't want to `ALTER` the column, only round the values, thanks!

Comment: And what DB engine do you use?

Comment: Column data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following would work for MySQL, SQL Server, and Postgres:

```
UPDATE PRICESTABLE
SET PRICE = ROUND(PRICE, 2);
```

You might want to add a `WHERE` clause to the above update, unless you really want to apply it to the entire table.  Also, an alternative here would be to keep all the original precision, and just call `ROUND` when you need to present the data.

Comment: @Carlos Can you mark this answer correct?  Also, tell us what database you are using.

Comment: The function to cut decimals as shown in the samples is not `ROUND` but `TRUNC` or `TRUNCATE` in most DBMS.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner `Notice I don't want to ALTER the column, only round the values, thanks!` ... if you're wondering why I answered with round, not trunc.  In any case, without knowing the exact database we can't give an answer for certain (though I tried).

Comment: Ah, sorry, so the OP is contradicting themselves. They show truncation and call it rounding. And you are right; the request is incomplete without the DBMS specified.

Comment: Thank you both I understood the difference! By the way I use SQL Server 2016